# Is it possible to specify scalar plot colours on Tensorboard?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard

Can you specify colours for scalar plots on Tensorboard? Either in code or using the UI. It's a bit annoying to have multiple plots of the same colour that I want to compare. The only way around it is to flick on/off the plot I'm looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. Tensorboard doesn't have that option

Have a look in here for more information:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/893

Comment: Thanks! That github thread is a little disappointing, hopefully someone adds it soon.

Comment: No problem @drfilip gang